# Prevent VPN disconnect

Tags: notifications

I installed DNS66 to use a custom hosts file to prevent access to certain websites. However it's easy to disconnect from it because a notification shows up permanently. I could use a blocking app to block access to the DNS66 app but I don't have a way to block access to the notification. Is there a way I can keep the VPN on permanently and make it difficult to disable?

[image]

Samsung S7 on Android 8.0.0

Comment: What android versions is in use? You should be able to hide the notifications entirely on newer versions by going to the Settings > Apps > DNS66.

Comment: The notification is from the system rather than the app itself. I've added deatils about the is.